# MySQL limit clause unusal issue

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id,name,info FROM table LIMIT 5
```

the result Set should be contains 5 rows wich is The first 5 rows of the table,but is any exception about this usage? .the table like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table limit 10;

 1. company_id company_name         tel
1   TCL集团股份有限公司 0752-2288333    
2   UNITEDSTACK（北京）科技有限公司   15727325616 
3   《市政技术》杂志社有限公司   13401070358 
4   《网络安全技术与应用》杂志社有限公司  010-62765013    
5   《艺术市场》杂志社股份有限公司 64271947
7   一呼医知己健康咨询（北京）有限公司   010-62957992
8   一呼（北京）电子商务有限公司  62957992    
9   一汽轿车股份有限公司  0431-85782608   
10  一通万通商务服务（北京）有限公司    010-68061805
```

I use the first sql the result is normal:like this

```
SELECT company_id,company_name,tel FROM table LIMIT 5;

 1. 1   TCL集团股份有限公司 0752-2288333
2   UNITEDSTACK（北京）科技有限公司   15727325616
3   《市政技术》杂志社有限公司   13401070358
4   《网络安全技术与应用》杂志社有限公司  010-62765013
5   《艺术市场》杂志社股份有限公司 64271947
```

However I use the second sql like this :

```
SELECT comapny_id,company_name FROM table LIMIT 5;


1275992 
1758051 
2990914 
5241776 
5344925
```

We are seeing the result is not the 5 rows of the table obviously,the difference of these fileds is that company_id is a primary key,company_name is a type of MUL.can you help me?thank you very much!

Comment: I am sorry that the format is not beautiful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the result Set should be contains 5 rows wich is The first 5 rows of
>   the table,but is any exception about this usage?

Only the first part of this statement is correct.  Your query returns 5 rows from the query.  However, those are 5 indeterminate rows.

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no first five rows in a table.  If you want your result set ordered, then you need to include an `order by` clause.  Often, an auto-incremented id is used for this purpose, because such an id captures the order that rows are inserted into the table.

Comment: As what you said ,the SQL tables represent unordered sets,Does it mean  the limit  5 clause  return 5 rows is unsertain ?  today I have test the sql with SELECT company_name FROM table LIMIT 5 ;and SELECT company_name,tel FROM table LIMIT 5, I got the result set with different company_name list. in the majority of cases the result set order is not change when use diffrent fileds?

Comment: Could you tell me why I get the different result set only use a different field ? because I get the same result set use other tables.I means that the specific field should be same.

Comment: @DLsky . . . When you use `limit` without an `order by`, you can get the data in any indeterminate order.  Period.  Running the same query twice could result in different rows.